# OnSaveInstanceState does not save the instance

Tags: android, onsaveinstancestate

I'm my app's onSaveInstanceState implementation. I've successfully implemented my onSaveInstanceState but it does not maintain the current question at orientation change. The following is my MainActivity. I've been following the book BigNerdRanchGuide from page to page. I don't understand why it isn't working.

Thanks.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public static final String TAG  = "QuizActivity";
        public static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";

        private TextView mTextView;
        private Button mTrueButton, mFalseButton;
        private ImageButton mNext, mPrev;

        private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[]{
                new Question((R.string.pacific_ocean), true),
                new Question((R.string.syria_europe), false),
                new Question((R.string.canada_na), true),
                new Question((R.string.africa_country), false),
                new Question((R.string.china_continent), false)
        };

        private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate(Bundle) called");

            if(savedInstanceState != null){
                mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
            }

            mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
            int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
            mTextView.setText(question);
...

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
            outState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
        }



        private void updateQuestion() {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
            mTextView.setText(question);
        }

        private void lastQuestion(){

            if (mCurrentIndex > 0){
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
                mTextView.setText(question);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "You're at the last question", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }

        private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue){
            boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

            int messageResId = 0;

            if(userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue){
                messageResId = R.string.correct;
            }else{
                messageResId = R.string.incorrect;
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I read your code well, what's happening is that you see the next question instead of the current one when the orientation changes, right?

Comment: Could you try to make a [mcve]? Do we need to see 5 buttons and all the lifecycle methods to figure out your error?

Comment: @cricket_007 I edited it.  MY apologies.

Comment: @IulianPopescu Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that `currentIndex=2`. When you rotate the screen and activity is recreated the `currentIndex` will have the save value. The issue here is that you were setting the question 2 times when the activity will be created: first here

```
int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
mTextView.setText(question);
```

and the second time at the end of `onCreate` (which is not visible anymore) by calling `updateQuestion()`. So, the value 2 will be in the end a 3 resulting in this weird behaviour. A possible solution for this would be to delete the first piece of code from above, subtract one from the current index and make sure to set the value of current index to -1 (you might have notice that the first question displayed is actually the second one in the array).

Comment: I just removed `updateQuestion()` from the `onCreate` and it did the trick

Comment: Glad that it worked! Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Sure.  Can you also upvote my question, since I think it did not warrant a -1.  It was a perfectly fine question.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know why but the BigNerdRanchGuide had me update the question at activity creation.  Seems rather unnecessary.